# Internal communication in AWS for microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 7 Spring microservices which I would like to deploy into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I see that I will be charged by outbound and inbound network traffic. It's not clear to me will I be charged for the internal communication between the microservices?

Answer (score 1):

> will I be charged for the internal communication between the microservices?

Depends. If all services are in same AZ and you use private IP addresses, they you will not be charged for traffic. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Data_Transfer):

> Data transferred between Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift, Amazon ElastiCache instances, and Elastic Network Interfaces in **the same Availability Zone is free**.

But if you spread your services across AZs, then you will be probably paying for the traffic:

> Data transferred "in" to and "out" from Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift, Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX), and Amazon ElastiCache instances, Elastic Network Interfaces or VPC Peering **connections across Availability Zones in the same AWS Region is charged at $0.01/GB** in each direction.

Cross-region traffic will also have cost.

Comment: the OP is asking for charges applicable to inter microservices communication, not inter AWS services communication.

Comment: @banavalikar Thanks, but its not clear from OP that all these microservices will be running on a single instance only or single AZ.